# How to get size of an element in an react app that is totally based on functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-functional-component

I have a react app that is purely built with functional components. I want to get the height of an element after it has been rendered on screen to change size of it's parent accordingly.

There are solutions for class based apps but I couldn't find any for functional components.

i tried this solution from answers but it is not running the useEffect hook

here is extracted code from my component

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
    MenuContainer,
    GrayBox,
    Wrapper

} from '../LayersMenu/LayerMenu.styles';


export const Component = ({ category, showStatistics }) => {
    const grayBoxRef= useRef(null);
    const wrapperRef= useRef(null);
    const testRef= useRef(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const height = wrapperRef.current.offsetHeight;
        console.log(height,'check');
      }, [wrapperRef])
    useEffect(()=>{
        const height = testRef.current.offsetHeight;
        console.log(height,'check2');
    },[testRef]);
    return (
        <MenuContainer ref={testRef}>
            <GrayBox ref={grayBoxRef}>
                <Wrapper ref={wrapperRef} hasAnyAllowedStats={showStatistics}>
                </Wrapper>
            </GrayBox>
        </MenuContainer>
    );
};
```

PS: accepted answer didn't work for my answer but it works for the project he added in answer works so i guess there is something wrong with my project structure or something not entirely sure.

Thanks alot for answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using class component with `componentDidMount` there is a hook called `useEffect` which can help you to catch somehow the rendered state of the component.

The solution to get height of a rendered DOM element can be the following with functional component:

```
 const YourComponent = () => {
   const inputRef = useRef(null);
   useEffect(() => {
      const height = inputRef.current.offsetHeight;
      console.log('Input height', height);   
   }, [inputRef]);

   return <>
     <input ref={inputRef} type="text" defaultValue="testing" />
   </>
}
```

**Explanation:**

`useRef` hook will help you to keep the reference for your object for the life of your component, as the documentation states:

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

Once you use `useEffect` combined with `useRef` just like in the above solution you will get the expected result. For `useEffect` hook the documentation explains:

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.

Passing `inputRef` to the dependency array will trigger the passed function on change of the `input` element for `useEffect`. Then the code calculates the height of your component which in this case just an `input` element. This can be any DOM element, just like a `div`.

**UPDATE:**

From your updated question, the solution is `forwardRef`, read in the documentation:

> Ref forwarding is a technique for automatically passing a ref through a component to one of its children.

With this technique you can access the child component's properties in the parent component e.g.: height of an internal `<div>` or `<input>` element what the code can use for further purposes.

In your child functional component, the code should use `forwardRef` in order to access internal DOM elements, just like below:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

// ...

const YourComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
   return <>
      <input ref={ref} type="text" defaultValue="testing" />
   </>
});
```

Then use in the parent component as the following:

```
const componentRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    const {offsetHeight} = componentRef.current;
    console.log('componentRef height', offsetHeight);   
}, [componentRef]);

return <>
    <YourComponent ref={componentRef} />
</>
```

If you are interested further then please find the documentation here: 
[Forwarding refs to DOM components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components)

Please find a working GitHub solution for your scenario what I just built up for representation:
[norbitrial/react-forwarding-ref-example](https://github.com/norbitrial/react-forwarding-ref-example)

Hope this gives you the idea to proceed further.

Comment: i tried this but callback function in useEffect is not running.

Comment: i am using styled components could that be a reason ?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq How did you define the callback with `useEffect`? I guess styled component should not be the reason, possibly.

Comment: added solution in question

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq Just updated the answer regarding `forwardRef` which helps you to achieve the goal. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for update , tried new solution and but still same effect, useEffect is not running even in parent component

by parent i mean 1 component up in hierarchy.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUlHaq Just added a GitHub repo what I made to represent my answer in more details. Please take a look, maybe that helps.

Comment: @norbitrial thanks for this helpful answer, but do you now what happens if the extraction of offsetHeight returns 0 instead of the real hight?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `useRef`-hook:

```
export const SomeComponent = () => {

const divRef= useRef(null);

   useEffect(()=>{
     if(divRef.current){
     // your logic
     }
   }, [divRef])

   return(
   <div ref={divRef}></div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Technically if you know you're passing the `ref` directly to an HTML element, you don't even need the `if` check.

Comment: Aw, it's my habit from TypeScript. But you are right, you won't need that in JavaScript.

Comment: That's what `divRef!.current` is for :)

Comment: Hello sir, i have added a solution i tried in the question, but useEffect callback is not working

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanUIHaq "it's not working" is not a problem statement.