# React - How to get height of the particular div if you know its class

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

I am new to react. I need help with getting height of the `coding` div. Here is the react code that I am working with as an example:

```
 const buttonDiv = () => (
    <div
      className={styles.coding}
    >
      <button
        className={styles.codingButton}
        onClick={() => doSomething()}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

So let say `styles.coding` class is `coding` and `styles.codingButton` is `coding-button`. Then there is another div with the class of let say `coding2`

How would I use the react to check and see what height for example was set on `coding` div.
Really what I am trying to do is translate this jquery to react

```
function dosomething() {
  if($('.coding').height() > 0){
    $('.coding').height('0')
    $('.coding2').height('100%')
  }
  else {
    $('.coding').height('50%')
    $('.coding2').height('49%')
  }
 }
```

Comment: Have you seen this question yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942210/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-in-an-react-app-that-is-totally-based-on-functiona. Also I wouldn't use jquery with react: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507205/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-jquery-in-reactjs

Comment: I am not using jquery with react.. I am trying to use the logic of this jquery and rewrite it using react... overall I am just trying to get the height of the element.

Comment: In jquery the DOM is the ultimate source of truth. This is not the case with react. In react we react based on state and props, not based on what is happening with some other piece of the DOM. So the question isn't does coding have a height, it's what causes coding's height to change? Once you know that you can work out the best way to notify coding2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above try to leverage `ref` to get what you want. Here's a little something that could maybe help you out. To see it work you can check it out here and use your console to check the logs. https://codepen.io/justdan/pen/zYwPWjp?editors=1010

```
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

const ButtonDiv = () => {
  const div = useRef(null);
  
  function doSomething() {
    const height = div.current.offsetHeight;
    console.log('height', height);
    
    if (height > 0) {
      console.log('hit');
    };
  };
  
  return ( 
    <div
      ref={div}
      className={'coding'}
    >
      <button
        className={'codingButton'}
        onClick={() => doSomething()}
      >
        Click Me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
      
ReactDOM.render(<ButtonDiv />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In context to the comment that you're not using jQuery, I prefer you use `window.getComputedStyle()` method and pass the ref to the div as the argument.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle